# One for loop for many tasks

Tags: scripting

The output of this code is two txt files. Can I make one for loop for both of them. i.e one for loop to give me two or more outputs?
In ID1 and ID2 I have names for files. I want to print the first line for every entry in ID1 and ID2 and save it as output1 and output2 but I don't want to use two for loops. What I am looking for is one for loop to do the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
in=/a/b/c
li=/a/b/c/d/
g1=/a/s/t1/1.txt
g2=/a/s/t2/2.txt

for i in $(cat $li/ID1.txt); do
    sed '1q;d' ${in}/${i}/${g1};
done > output1.txt

for i in $(cat $li/ID2.txt); do
    sed '1q;d' ${in}/${i}/${g2};
done > output2.txt
```

Comment: are you trying to get `sed` to print the first line from several filenames as stored in `ID[12].txt` and write the outputs respectively?

Comment: layer it: `for m in ID[12].txt; do for f in $(cat $m); do IFS= read -r l <"$f"; printf %s\\n "$l"; done >"output${m#??}"; done`. But that doesn't address all of the possible problems with `$IFS` and etc that you might have already doing `for something in $(cat file)` and so I can't make it any better without looking at the input and making sense of all of those filenames in the variables. You should probably quote more.

Comment: You can alter the outfile of a loop at any time with `exec >outfile` as well, but you'd need some marker to test for during the loop execution to call it at the right time. Like if you had 5 filenames in ID1 and 10 in ID2 you could do `i=0;for ... [ "$((i+=1))" -eq 6 ] && exec >outfile2...` but the comment I left before nests two loops while dynamically setting the outfile name based on the infile name.

Comment: Can you please [edit] and give us some examples? Your current script will produce paths like `/a/b/c/foo/a/s/t1/1.txt`. This seems like a needlessly complicated way to do things. Why don't you take a step back and give us some examples of your paths and what you really want to do here.

Comment: As I said, we cold be more specific if you explained what you're doing in more detail, but see my updated answer for another, more general, shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you don't need a loop at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
in=/a/b/c
li=/a/b/c/d/
g1=/a/s/t1/1.txt
g2=/a/s/t2/2.txt

files1=$(sed "s#^#${in}/#;s#\$#/${g1}#" $li/ID1.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
files2=$(sed "s#^#${in}/#;s#\$#/${g2}#" $li/ID2.txt | tr '\n' ' ')

head -qn 1 $files1 > output1
head -qn 1 $files2 > output2
```

The `files1=...` used `sed` to add `$in` to the start of each line and `$g1` to the end. This should result in a list of target filenames. You can then pass all of the to the `sed` that prints the 1st line.

**IMPORTANT**: This assumes that your file names are sane (contain no spaces, newlines or other strange characters). If this is not the case, please let me know and I will try and provide a more robust answer. Note that your original approach with the `for` loop would also fail on file names with spaces.

---

In general, whatever the language you are working in, if you find yourself writing repetitive code, you should think about a function instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

in=/a/b/c
li=/a/b/c/d/
g1=/a/s/t1/1.txt
g2=/a/s/t2/2.txt

firstline(){
    _in="$1"
    _g="$2"
    file="$3"
    while read i
    do
        sed '1q;d' ${in}/${i}/${g}
    done < "$file"
}

firstline "$li/ID1.txt" "$in" "$g1"  > output1.txt
firstline "$li/ID2.txt" "$in" "$g2"  > output2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand what the pathnames in the variables do now.

```
for n in 1 2; do n=$n.txt
for f in $(cat "$li/ID$n")
do IFS= read -r l <"$in/$f/a/s/t${n%.*}/$n"
    printf %s\\n "$l"
done > "output$n"; done
```

I *think* that accomplishes what you're after. If so, it does it all with shell built-ins - that is, excepting `cat`.

And speaking of `cat` - when splitting with `$IFS` as you do here with the `for ... in $(cmd sub)` it is important to be explicit about the value of `$IFS` and to `set -f` to avoid filename globs being interpreted in the expansion. Because I do not know the contents of the file though, I can't advise any more than that.

Another way could involve a null string delimiter. This is highly dependent on the `$IFS` splitting though - it depends on the expansion *not* including any null strings because it uses one as a marker. If you are not altering `$IFS` and it is set to its default value, then the `$(cat file)` expansion won't include any null strings. It could go something like this:

```
io=/a/s/t1/1.txt
for f in $(cat "$li/ID1.txt") '' $(cat "$li/ID2.txt")
do [ -z "$f" ] && io=/a/s/t2/2.txt && continue
IFS= read -r l <"$in/$f/$io"
printf %s\\n "$l" >> "output${io##*/}"
done
```

Or you might even do...

```
n=0
for f in '' $(cat "$li/ID1.txt") '' $(cat "$li/ID2.txt")
do [ -z "$f" ] && exec >"output$((n+=1)).txt" && continue
IFS= read -r l <"$in/$f/a/s/t$n/$n.txt"
printf %s\\n "$l"
done
```